# How to activate a GitHub plugin via the wordpress script that was installed by npm?

Tags: wordpress, github, npm

I'm trying to install a plugin for my video.js on wordpress, made available via github for npm, I've already installed the plugin via npm and everything, however, I can't activate the plugin at all, where do I properly place the correct place in the script?

the plugin can be found at:
https://github.com/chrisboustead/videojs-vtt-thumbnails

my only problem is to activate it and use it!

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is not a wordpress plugin. You could use it in your theme or you could use it in a plugin you create yourself.

Wordpress does not use the plugins installed with npm.
What you could do to include it in your site by creating a small plugin with an php file that automatic loads in the files of the node modules with a hook. Or you could include it in a theme by including it in your header.php.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding me! I am new to the business of creating websites, I will try to go your way now so to install!